# Best way to pass previous URL string on to current page?

Tags: url, http-headers

**Thanks for reading this.** I would like to pass on the previous page URL (i.e. the http:// etc) that my visitor was previously on - to the page that are currently on....

So, say for example before reading this post you were looking at another stackoverflow question then the CURRENT page, i.e. **this one**, would have a message box saying something like "Your last page visited was stackoverflow/questions/issue/123"

I think that could be done using headers?

Please note that I would have complete control over what I can place on the Previous AND Current page - b/c it would all be on the same site. Thanks and I hope that makes sense. Thanks again for reading.

Answer (score 0):

You do not need to 'pass' it, the Browser already passes it automatically as part of the http `Request Headers`, the header name is `Referer`.